# Image shaking when Manipulate with slider

Tags: graphics, manipulate

How to prevent the `Graphics3D` object in following code from shaking when continuously changing the `phi` parameter?

```
(*magnetic field*)
magneticField = {Arrowheads[{{Small, 0.3}, {Small, 0.7}}], 
   Arrow /@ 
    Transpose@
     Flatten[Table[{i, 
          j, #}, {i, {-1.5, 0, 1.5}}, {j, {-1.5, 0, 1.5}}] & /@ {-3, 
        3}, {{1}, {2, 3}, {4}}]};
(*points of current*)
current[l_, θ_, ϕ_] := 
  current[2, 90 Degree, ϕ] = {-0.5 l {Sin[θ] Cos[ϕ], 
      Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ], Cos[θ]}, 
    0.5 l {Sin[θ] Cos[ϕ], Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ], 
      Cos[θ]}};
Manipulate[
 (*wire*)
 wire = {Blue, Arrowheads[{{Medium, 0.9}}], 
   Arrow[Tube@current[2, 90 Degree, phi]]};
 (*Ampere force*)
 force = {Red, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, 
     Cross[(#2 - #1) & @@ current[2, 90 Degree, phi], {0, 0, 1}]}]};
 (*graphics*)
 Graphics3D[{magneticField, wire, force}, Axes -> False, 
  SphericalRegion -> True, Boxed -> False]
 , {phi, 0, 2 π, 0.1 π}]
```

I actually tried setting `ViewVector -> {{6, 6, 6}, {0, 0, 0}}`. It worked, *but* it sacrificed the ability to maintain the viewpoint when `phi` is continuously changed.

So what are the proper options to prevent image from shaking when `phi` is continuously changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}` to your `Graphics3D`

Comment: Well...`Axes->False` blinded me...